# Структура для решения функции комплексного переменного

Tags: c#, .net

Добрый день.

Программа вычисления функции (exp^z) c некоторой точностью,посредством разложения в ряд. Реализация через структуру. Данная программа отрабатывает правильно с маленькими степенями (1+1i),(2+1i). На степени (3+3i) и больше выдает "NaN". Думаю,что дело с типами данных, т.к. факториалы больших чисел уже не обрабатываются правильно.Можно ли как-то решить эту проблему?

Заранее спасибо.

```
    class Program
    {
       // Дано комплексное число z и вещественное число eps.Вычислить с точностью еps значение комплексной функции
       //exp(z) = 1 + z/1! + z^2/2! +...+ z^n/n! +...
        public struct Complex
        {

            public double i, r;
            public Complex(double r,double i)
            {
                this.i = i;
                this.r = r;
            }
            static public Complex Sum(Complex a,Complex b)
            {
                Complex cx = new Complex();
                cx.r = a.r + b.r;
                cx.i = a.i + b.i;
                return cx;
            }
            static public Complex Power(Complex a,long n)
            {
                if (n == 0 || n == 1) return a;
                Complex cx = new Complex();
                double arg=0;
                if (a.r > 0) arg =Math.Atan(a.i /a.r);
                if (a.r < 0 && a.i >= 0) arg = Math.PI + Math.Atan(a.i/a.r);
                if (a.r < 0 && a.i < 0) arg = -Math.PI +Math.Atan(a.i /a.r);
                if (a.r == 0&&a.i>0) arg =Math.PI / 2;
                if (a.r == 0 && a.i < 0) arg =-Math.PI / 2;
                cx.r =Math.Pow(Complex.abs(a), n) * (Math.Cos(n*arg));
                cx.i =Math.Pow(Complex.abs(a), n) * (Math.Sin(n * arg));
                return cx;

            }
             static public Complex Division(Complex a,long n)// деление комплексного числа на целое
            {  
                Complex cx = new Complex();
                cx.r = (a.r * n) / (n * n);
                cx.i = (a.i * n) / (n * n);
                return cx;
            }
            static public double abs (Complex a)
            {
                 double result =Math.Sqrt((a.r * a.r) +(a.i * a.i));
                 return result;
            }
            static public Complex exp(Complex z, double eps)
            {
                long i = 1;
                Complex sum = new Complex();
                sum.r = 1;
                sum.i = 0;
                Complex tmp = new Complex();
                tmp.i = 0;
                tmp.r = 1;

                while (Complex.abs(tmp) > eps)
                {
                    tmp = Complex.Division(Complex.Power(z, i), Factorial(i));
                    sum = Complex.Sum(sum, tmp);
                    i++;
                }
                return sum;

            }
        }
        static public long Factorial(long n)
        {
            long result = 1;
            if (n == 0) return result;
            for (long i = n; i >= 1; i--)
                result = result * i;

            return result;
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Complex z1 = new Complex();
            Complex z2 = new Complex();
            z1.r = 4;
            z1.i = -2;
            double eps =0.1;
            z2 = Complex.exp(z1, eps);
            Console.WriteLine(z2.r);
            Console.WriteLine(z2.i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Не нужно вычислять сумму ряда, программируя её "в лоб" по формуле. Не нужно вычислять `z^n/n!`. Вам нужно предыдущий член последовательности сохранять в переменную, а последующий вычислять умножением предыдущего на `z/n` и потом добавлять к сумме.

Comment: Если что, с .NET 4 есть специальный тип [Complex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.complex(v=vs.110).aspx).